# Swift Data initialization slow and memory inefficient with large dataset

Tags: objective-c, swift, performance, nsdata

If I try and initialize a Swift `Data` struct with a relatively large `MutableRandomAccessSlice<Data>` the program starts grows large in memory use and takes a long time to finish. However, doing the same thing in Objective-C with `NSData` appears to not have the same problem.

For example, with the following code:

```
let startData = Data(count: 100_000_000)
let finalData = Data(startData[0..<95_234_877])
```

if I compile it using:

```sh
xcrun swiftc -O -sdk `xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx` -o output main.swift
```

the execution (on my MacBook Air 2011) takes a long time to finish (87s) and the memory usage is through the roof (see up to 625MB below):

```sh
$ time ./output
./output  85.21s user 1.29s system 99% cpu 1:26.91 total

$ top -o MEM
PID    COMMAND      %CPU  TIME     #TH   #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP  PPID  STATE
38156  output       99.0  01:25.57 1/1   0    10    625M+  0B     992M+  38156 36025 running
```

If I profile each step it takes about 0.00015s to create `startData`, 0.000007s to create the slice from `startData`, and the rest of the time to initialize `finalData`.

If I do the same thing in Objective-C:

```c
NSData *startData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:100000000];
NSData *finalData = [startData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 95234877)];
```

it only takes roughly 0.00017s.

Am I doing something wrong in the Swift example? There seems to be a very large discrepency between the two.

Comment: Does `startData` or `finalData` take up the bulk of the execution time? (You can find out by using print statements for such a long execution time)

Comment: Good point, I forgot to add that. I've edited the question above with those details. Nearly all of the time is taken initializing `finalData` with the slice.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `subdata(in:Range)` in swift?

Comment: I checked subdata(in:Range) and it works quickly

Comment: Hmm that's a good point ;) Forgot about that method. However, I wonder why it's so much more inefficient if you initialize it with a slice. Even if `subdata(in:)` is doing something clever like not making a copy of the data, I wouldn't expect the slice initialization to take so long and use so much memory. But using `subdata(in:)` does indeed produce much better results.

Comment: Looks like the following code has a similar problem: `Data([UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 100_000_000))`. Takes about 0.06s to create the array, but ~60s to create the Data object from the array and memory usage is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found, the Objective-C code `[startData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 95234877)]` is equivalent to `startData.subdata(in: 0..<95_234_877)`.

When you write `Data(startData[0..<95_234_877])`, Swift calls `public convenience init<S : Sequence where S.Iterator.Element == Iterator.Element>(_ elements: S)` of `RangeReplaceableCollection`, it's defined in [RangeReplaceableCollection.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/RangeReplaceableCollection.swift.gyb). The core part of the implementation is like this:

```
for element in newElements {
  append(element)
}
```

You know repeating `append` to a collection may be inefficient.

And, if you want to initialize a `Data` from `[UInt8]`, you'd better call an initializer specific for `[UInt8]`:

```
let data = Data(bytes: [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 10_000_000))
```

`Data([UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 100_000_000))` calls the initializer in `RangeReplaceableCollection` noted above.

---

In my opinion, Swift should optimize such default implementations much more, but hard to make them as efficient as type specific operations.